# whats wrong with this reg ex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this reg ex

```
var id = url.match(/(\d+)\/\d+$/)[1];
```

that is parsing a url

```
http://whatever.com/something/70/48/359
```

It is grabbing the 48 as it should but it fails on

```
http://whatever.com/something/70/48/359#
```

why is the # messing up the regex

Comment: The second URL does not end with a digit but with `#`.

Comment: Where does `url` come from? If it’s the current document’s location, better use `location.pathname` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this regular expression instead:

```
/(\d+)\/\d+(?:$|[?#])/
```

This matches not just the end of the string but also the delimiters for the query (`?`) and the fragment (`#`).

And if your `url` happens to be the document’s location (e.g. `location.href`), better use `location.pathname` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Because of the ...`\d+$` which means "after the last number the end of the URL must follow immediately" (with no # inbetween).

Answer (score 2):

The `#` is not a digit. Try:

```
(\d+)\/\d+#?$
```

Answer (score 2):

The `$` at the end anchors the regex to the end of the URL, meaning it will only match if the two numbers come right at the end. You can add `(#.*)?` to the end to allow for an optional `#anchor`:

```
// Allow optional anchor.
var id = url.match(/(\d+)\/\d+(#.*)?$/)[1];
```

You may also want to allow a query string as well, the part after a question mark. For that add `(\?.*?)?` as well:

```
// Allow optional query string and anchor.
var id = url.match(/(\d+)\/\d+(\?.*?)?(#.*)?$/)[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Because it is expecting the string to end with digits, because of the dollar sign in `\d+$`.

Here's your regex fixed to ignore `#anchors` and `?query=strings`:

```
var id = url.match(/(\d+)\/\d+(|#.*|\?.*)$/)[1];
```

The `(|#.*|\?.*)` part will either match nothing, #anything or ?anything.

Or more efficiently:

```
var id = url.match(/(\d+)\/\d+([#\?].*)?$/)[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the `\d+` and `$` indicates that the line must end with one or more digits. As the second example ends with `#` there's no match in that case.

Answer (score 1):

The $ anchors your regexp to the end of the string. Since # is not a digit, the regexp won't match the second example.

Answer (score 1):

The `\d+$` part means "one or more digits, followed by the end of string".  If there's a `#` in between, it no longer matches.

If all you want to do is allow a final `#` sign, try:

```
/(\d+)\/\d+\#?$/
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly a fix to the regex, but you can stop the "#" from showing up in the URL by changing the links that are `<a href="#">` to be `<a href="#" onclick="return false;">`

It would probably be easier to do it unobtrusively with jQuery like this...

```
$(function() {
  $("a[href=\\#]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work if the user has JavaScript disabled. (But if JS is required to use the site it doesn't really matter.)

Answer (score 1):

`var id = url.match(/(\d+)\/\d+#?$/)[1];`

Will fix ya

Answer (score 0):

```
.match(/(\d+)\/\d+[^\/]*$/)[1]
```